# How to pass parameters to HTML web resource?

Tags: dialog, dynamics-crm-2011, webresource

I created one HTML web resource. It is opened in modal dialog after click on some ribbon button. Configuration of ribbon button is shown on picture below.

[image]

Now, after this is imported and published in CRM, I'm getting an error:

[image]

What did I miss here?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to setup a publisher :) new_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found where is problem. In Ribbon configuration I needed to set CRM parameter name to **Data** instead of PlayersIDs